# Every group it a permutation of itself

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I understand that Cayley's theorem says (roughly?) that every group is a permutation. (Is this true?)

If every group is a permutation of itself, is this permutation unique? Why?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Cayley’s theorem says that any group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\text{Sym}(G)$, the group of permutations of $G$ (i.e. bijections from $G$ to itself).

Comment: Rather, Cayley's theorem says that every group *element* is a permutation in disguise.

Answer (score 2):

No. Cayley's theorem does not say that the group is "a permutation".

It says that every group is ("the same as", i.e. "isomorphic to") a group of (some, not necessarily all) permutations on (some) set. For example the group given by the following table: $$\begin{array}{c|ccc}\cdot &a&b&c\\\hline a&a&b&c\\b&b&c&a\\c&c&a&b\end{array}$$ can be viewed as a group of three permutations on the set $\{a,b,c\}$ given by the very *rows* of this table.

Neither the set nor the permutations of it are unique, in fact in our case you can have any $3$-element set and make one permutation an identity and use two other permutations that "rotate" the three elements one way and another.